# Linux overcommit memory setting

Tags: linux, memory

According to this document: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting , if I set "vm.overcommit_memory" to "2", then "The total address space commit for the system is not permitted to exceed swap + a configurable amount (default is 50%) of physical RAM." Also, "The overcommit amount can be set via 'vm.overcommit_ratio' (percentage) or 'vm.overcommit_kbytes' (absolute value)."

My question is, are the "vm.overcommit_ratio" and "vm.overcommit_kbytes" limiting the total sum of memory commit by all processes, or just limiting each process?

I think it should be the latter, because it makes no sense to limit the system to use only half of physical memory in total, but the description in the document suggests it is limiting globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is global.  The purpose of the setting is to make sure that you can not use up *all* of your memory and cause the OOM killer to start killing processes.

Answer (score 3):

> I think it should be the latter,

It's the former.

> because it makes no sense to limit the system to use only half of physical memory in total, but the description in the document suggests it is limiting globally.

Agreed. But this is not a limit on how much physical memory is used. As it says, it limits committed address space, not physical memory usage. Of course the system will use pretty much all of its RAM.

Comment: So if I disable overcommit and disable swap, this value should be 100 right?

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure what value you're talking about. But if you mean the amount of permitted committed address space, with no swap and a value of 100, system behavior could become very pathological as RAM gets cluttered with dirty pages that will almost never be used and the system has no place to eject them. The set of clean pages could get very badly squeezed resulting on atrocious performance and constant discarding and re-loading of clean pages.

Comment: Yes I mean "vm.overcommit_memory=2" and "vm.overcommit_ratio=100". So you mean it shouldn't be 100? But lower than that would mean I cannot even make use of all my RAM if I disable overcommit and disable swap, right?

Comment: @Sam You can make use of all your RAM. Again, that is *not* a setting of what percentage of your RAM will be used. (But yes, no matter how you set anything, it is impossible to make good use of all your RAM without swap. Swap exists to allow us to make efficient use of RAM. See my comment above.)